# Docker build failing while installing pandas in docker in python2.7-alpine

Tags: python, pandas, docker, python-2.7, pip

I am running a flask application in Docker. I am also using Pandas. I am using python2.7-alpine image. Earlier it was working fine i.e. I was able to build images with the same configuration.

But now I am unable to build the image as it says:

```
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Sm9A7D/pandas/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I cannot change the python version. As my application is built on python2 and was as expected for a long back.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules; 
#    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main" > /etc/apk/repositories; \
#    echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
#    echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
#    echo "http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
#    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
#    echo "http://dl-5.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    apk update && \
    apk add --update bash sudo


#================================================================
# add dependencies
#================================================================

RUN apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libffi-dev make gpgme p11-kit openssl-dev openssh

#================================================================
# pip and required modules install
#================================================================

### Upgrade pip to prevent errors
RUN pip install setuptools --upgrade
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

The full error track back is:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Sm9A7D/pandas/setup.py", line 749, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 717, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 784, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-2BV0tR/numpy-1.17.0rc1/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        def is_platform_mac():
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Sm9A7D/pandas/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Can you show what is in your `requirements.txt` file? If you say that it is failing while installing `pandas`, which version of `pandas` are you installing?

Comment: @bunji ```pandas==0.23.4```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you the reason:

> File "/tmp/easy_install-r9No9Q/numpy-1.17.0rc1/setup.py", line 31, in 
>         def is_platform_mac():
>      RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.

From pandas 0.23.4 [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/setup.py#L44): we can see the minimum version for numpy is `1.9.0`:

> min_numpy_ver = '1.9.0'

So, if you did not install a version by yourself, pandas will just install a newest suitable version of numpy which `>1.9.0` for you, here is `numpy-1.17.0rc1`, but it needs `>python3.5` as seen [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0rc1/setup.py#L406), so failure happens.

> python_requires='>=3.5'

Finally, if you check the source code of numpy, you will find `1.16.4` is the last version which support python2.7, see [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.4/setup.py#L378),

```
python_requires='>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*',
```

**So, final solution**:

Pre-install numpy 1.16.4, then pandas find there is a suitable numpy there, and will not install a newest numpy for you. As a result, no error will happen, detail steps as next:

```
apk update
apk add build-base
pip install numpy==1.16.4
pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

For `Dockerfile`, add above command to one RUN could make the fix:

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add build-base && \
    pip install numpy==1.16.4 && \
    pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

Additional, you said in question:

> Earlier it was working fine i.e. I was able to build images with the same configuration.

This is because [numpy latest version](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0rc1/setup.py) was just updated July.1st 2019, before that, it always `1.16.4` version which don't have issue for python27, but now, things changed...